# Error setting kb layout with `setxkbmap`

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, x11-forwarding

I have x11-forwarding set up from an ubuntu 12.04 vm to my (windows) laptop. It works, but when I type in the forwarded applications, it is using the qwerty layout and I would like it to use colemak.

I would like a command-line solution since I don't have the GUI installed in the vm.

I have tried `setxkbmap -v us -variant colemak`, but I get "Error loading new keyboard description":

```
$ setxkbmap -v us -variant colemak
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Warning! Multiple definitions of layout variant
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   xfree86+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(colemak)
geometry:   pc(pc101)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

I also tried `setxkbmap -v us -variant dvorak`, which did seem to work.

What is wrong? Colemak comes with ubuntu, and I can see a section for it in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, which is where the layout is defined, I assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake was assuming that the keyboard layouts that were important were the ones in the vm (/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/).

Actually, when using x-forwarding it is the keyboard layouts defined in my x server, xming (C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\xkb\symbols) that are important, and colemak is not included with xming by default. I was able to just download the colemak definition and drop it in the xming symbols folder; then it works as expected.

Comment: ... a few years later: What definition did you download, if you still remember? :)

Comment: The layout is available at http://colemak.com/Unix

Comment: Thanks Gabe! I've since found it. I actually grabbed the one from DreymaR's big bag of tricks forum topic, as that gave me the full directory, and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, I can correctly switch to `colemak` with your command:

```
#> setxkbmap -v us -variant colemak
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Warning! Multiple definitions of layout variant
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us(colemak)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

but I can't if I try to keep my Italian variant:

```
#> setxkbmap -v it -variant colemak
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Warning! Multiple definitions of layout variant
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+it(colemak)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

I'd suggest to you [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/), but given that you don't have any desktop manager installed it will be pretty useless.

However, the motivation should be this one:

```
#> grep colemak /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb:xkb_symbols "colemak" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb:    include "us(colemak)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv:// http://colemak.com/
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv:xkb_symbols "colemak" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv:xkb_symbols "apostrophecolemak" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv:  include "lv(colemak)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ph:// http://colemak.com
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ph:xkb_symbols "colemak" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ph:xkb_symbols "colemak-bay" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us:// 2006-01-01 Shai Coleman, http://colemak.com/ . Public domain.
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us:xkb_symbols "colemak" {
```

I can choose the `colemak` layout among `gb`, `lv`, `ph` and `us` languages only. You should have a similar problem.

At the end of the story, you can do two things: select `colemak` for a language close to `us` that you have installed (e.g. `uk` or `gb`), or try to install `colemak` support for `us` language via command line (I really don't know how, sorry).

Comment: Thanks. This didn't solve my problem, but it pointed me in the right direction. Looks like it is my X server (xming) that needs colemak installed, and not the vm.

Comment: When you say that "you can only use colemak with some language/locale", it occurs to me that the variant and language settings are found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/`, in `base.lst` and `base.xml`. There you can find the whole list of variants of languages, maybe you can customize which language can use `colemak`. Just a guess but very much possible.

Comment: Actually, I find that `xkb_symbols` is the name of variant of some keyboard layout under some language. If you examine some file, like `es` under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, you can see that the first one is the base, with `default` in the first line, `xkb_symbols` is always `basic`, and others will not have `default` in the definition, and `xkb_symbols` will have distinct names. So, I guess you can load a keymap with `setxkbmap xxx -variant colemak`. Before that, ensure the keymap file `us` has a section of `xkb_symbols "colemak"` actually present.

Comment: for TcXsrv I could update my launch file with something like this: `vcxsrv.exe -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -ac -xkbmodel pc105 -xkblayout us -xkbvariant colemak`