# how to change the keyboard layout for all programs from the command line?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/533748/138891) I have verified that I have the "US, international with dead keys" keyboard layout available:

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst | grep US,\ international\ with\ 
  intl            us: English (US, international with dead keys)
```

Then, based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196842/89663), I try to change the keyboard layout from the command line. But `setxkbmap -v intl` fails:

```
$ setxkbmap -v intl
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+intl+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

System is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am on a desktop system, using i3wm.

## update

Ok, so apparently the following succeeds:

```
$ setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us -variant intl
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: What kind of system do you have? Desktop, server? If the former, which desktop environment?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson desktop, i3wm

Comment: See that you figured it out. Great! Please feel free to submit the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant on the US layout keyboard, so the following succeeds:

```
$ setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout us -variant intl
$ echo $?
0
```

In fact, the `-model pc105` part wasn't even necessary in my case.